# Save parent and child entities at same with a notnull foreignkey towards the parent (Spring JPA / Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one, bidirectional-relation

I've two entities in a MySQL DB and I want to realize a bi-directional mapping, with an automatic save of the new child when save a new parent.

MACCHINA (parent) fields: id, marca

PERSONA (child) fields: id, nome, macchina_id (foreign key NOT NULL)

When I save a new MACCHINA, I want also to save a new PERSONA by this JSON:

```
{
  "marca": "string",
  "personas": [
    {
      "nome": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

**MACCHINA entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "macchina")
public class Macchina implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "marca", nullable = false)
    private String marca;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "macchina", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Persona> personas = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

**PERSONA entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
public class Persona implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "nome", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="macchina_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Macchina macchina;

        // getters and setters ...
    }
```

In this scenario, when I call the JPA repository method .save() on the Macchina entity, I've the exception:

```
> Caused by:
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> Column 'macchina_id' cannot be null
```

In this same scenario, I tried to remove in the database, the NotNull constraint to the field "macchina_id" in the Persona table; in this case, the transaction is executed, but the "macchina_id" field in the Persona table, is NULL.

I found a work-around by removing the NotNull constraint to the "macchina_id" in the database (and annotations in the entity) AND by modifying the mapping from parent towards child in this way:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "macchina_id")
private Set<Persona> personas = new HashSet<>();
```

I removed "mappedBy" and added the @JoinColumn.
In this way it works: Hibernate execute an insert into Macchina, an insert into Persona, and finally an update into Persona (I guess to write/update the macchina_id field).

My goal is to mantain the NotNull properties for the field "macchina_id" in the database; mantain some properties values in the child entity on the mapping field `private Macchina macchina;` like @NotNull / nullable = false / @ManyToOne(optional = false) and save the both entities at the same time with the "macchina_id" field validated automatically by Spring/Hibernate, without to write code by hand.

So, there is an automatic way (Spring/Hibernate) to save first the parent and then the children who has a NotNull foreign key towards the parent?

Any suggestion?

Regards, Andrea

Comment: before saving `Macchina`, add `Macchina` to every `PERSONA`, also set `CascadeType.All` or `Persist` if you want to only save

Comment: Show us your code how you are saving

Comment: Showed in a new answer

Comment: As said, before saving `Macchina`, add `Macchina` to every `PERSONA`

Comment: Also show code of `macchinaMapper.toEntity(macchinaDTO);`

Comment: Added the code of `macchinaMapper.toEntity(macchinaDTO);` but I don't know if it is useful for this case

Answer (score 1):

I had the **exact** same problem, and found this thread after much searching. And I finally solved it.
Basically, JPA (or Hibernate - not sure), doesn't seem to be able to set the parent-reference in the child by itself (even though you set the annotations). So in the **ParentEntity** you should do something along the lines of:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentReference", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // parentReference, the property in ChildEntity class
    private final List<ChildEntity> childEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    public ParentEntity(ParentDTO parentDTO) {
        ...
        this.childEntities.add(new ChildEntity(parentDTO.getChildDTO(), this)); // NOTE second param "this"
    }
}
```

And in the **ChildEntity**, set the parent reference

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_foreign_key_column_name", nullable = false)
    private final ParentEntity parentReference;

    public ChildEntity(ChildDTO child, ParentEntity parentReference) {
        ...
        this.parentReference = parentReference;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code used to do the save is very simple: I receive from REST the JSON into a DTO, then I map the DTO into a domain object, and finally I call the method .save() of JpaRepository.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MacchinaDTO save(MacchinaDTO macchinaDTO) {
    log.debug("Request to save Macchina : {}", macchinaDTO);
    Macchina macchina = macchinaMapper.toEntity(macchinaDTO);
    macchina = macchinaRepository.save(macchina);
    return macchinaMapper.toDto(macchina);
}
```

Comment: Add this to your question

Answer (score 0):

I would like to try to avoid to add `Macchina` to every `Persona` by hand. I'm trying to manage this by Spring/Hibernate (because in case I remove the not null constraint from the foreign key, it works).

To do this example, I'm using a project generated with the project generator JHipster (if you know), and it uses MapStruct to map DTO and domain:

```
/**
 * Contract for a generic dto to entity mapper.
 @param <D> - DTO type parameter.
 @param <E> - Entity type parameter.
 */

public interface EntityMapper <D, E> {
    public E toEntity(D dto);
    public D toDto(E entity);
    public List <E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);
    public List <D> toDto(List<E> entityList);
}

/**
 * Mapper for the entity Macchina and its DTO MacchinaDTO.
 */
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {PersonaMapper.class})
public interface MacchinaMapper extends EntityMapper <MacchinaDTO, Macchina> {

    default Macchina fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Macchina macchina = new Macchina();
        macchina.setId(id);
        return macchina;
    }
}

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2017-07-21T11:57:12+0200",
    comments = "version: 1.1.0.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 3.12.3.v20170228-1205, environment: Java 1.8.0_141 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class MacchinaMapperImpl implements MacchinaMapper {

    @Autowired
    private PersonaMapper personaMapper;

    @Override
    public MacchinaDTO toDto(Macchina arg0) {
        if ( arg0 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        MacchinaDTO macchinaDTO = new MacchinaDTO();

        macchinaDTO.setId( arg0.getId() );
        macchinaDTO.setMarca( arg0.getMarca() );
        Set<PersonaDTO> set = personaSetToPersonaDTOSet( arg0.getPersonas() );
        if ( set != null ) {
            macchinaDTO.setPersonas( set );
        }

        return macchinaDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MacchinaDTO> toDto(List<Macchina> arg0) {
        if ( arg0 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<MacchinaDTO> list = new ArrayList<MacchinaDTO>();
        for ( Macchina macchina : arg0 ) {
            list.add( toDto( macchina ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Macchina toEntity(MacchinaDTO arg0) {
        if ( arg0 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Macchina macchina = new Macchina();

        macchina.setId( arg0.getId() );
        macchina.setMarca( arg0.getMarca() );
        Set<Persona> set = personaDTOSetToPersonaSet( arg0.getPersonas() );
        if ( set != null ) {
            macchina.setPersonas( set );
        }

        return macchina;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Macchina> toEntity(List<MacchinaDTO> arg0) {
        if ( arg0 == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Macchina> list = new ArrayList<Macchina>();
        for ( MacchinaDTO macchinaDTO : arg0 ) {
            list.add( toEntity( macchinaDTO ) );
        }

        return list;
    }

    protected Set<PersonaDTO> personaSetToPersonaDTOSet(Set<Persona> set) {
        if ( set == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<PersonaDTO> set_ = new HashSet<PersonaDTO>();
        for ( Persona persona : set ) {
            set_.add( personaMapper.toDto( persona ) );
        }

        return set_;
    }

    protected Set<Persona> personaDTOSetToPersonaSet(Set<PersonaDTO> set) {
        if ( set == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Set<Persona> set_ = new HashSet<Persona>();
        for ( PersonaDTO personaDTO : set ) {
            set_.add( personaMapper.toEntity( personaDTO ) );
        }

        return set_;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I would like to try to avoid to add Macchina to every Persona by hand.`, Since your are not mapping `Macchina` to `Persona` from view you have to do it **manually**. OR you can Map Macchina to Persona **personaDTOSetToPersonaSet** here also\